# upload.php is not working on my server

Tags: php, html, upload

The following script was copied over form W3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp.

The script is not uploading images into the uploads/ directory - is there something wrong with my script? Or is there something additional that needs to be implemented in order for the script to work?

**Directory name:** "uploads/"

**file name:** "upload.php"

```html
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

EDITS

---

[image]

The above errors now occur from the following script

```html
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Copy the file to target folder
    if ($uploadOk) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], target_dir .  $target_file );
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check if the directory has the  proper permissions for writting in: *755*

Comment: @R. Jones, have you tried to configure the php.ini file on  'file_uploads = On' to allow uploads on your server

Comment: I have contacted my hosting provider, and checked the php.ini and file_uploads is activated. 'file_uploads = On'

Comment: @R. Jones from your code you are missing some codes that will upload the file to your server, from your code above you are simply checking whether its ok to upload or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any function in your code to copy the uploaded file into the target directory.

You have to add this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir .  $target_file )
```

**Attending the question author comment in this post, I updated the code to create the folder if it does not exist.**

So your code should result like:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Copy the file to target folder
    if ($uploadOk) {

       // Check if the upload directory exists and create if necessary
       if (!is_dir($target_dir)) {
           mkdir($target_dir);
       }

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir .  $target_file );
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the response, please see the edits above in order to see the new problem

Comment: @R.Jones I corrected the code, it had a syntax error. And I create the folder if it does not exist ;)